# Is mesi cache coherence protocol applicable for single processor with 2 logical cores?

Tags: caching, multicore, mesi

I am using Intel Atom Processor (Genuine Intel (R) CPU). I have done cat/proc/cpuinfo. It is showing two processors but for physical and core id, it is showing 0. I did grep "^core id" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l to find no of cpu cores. It is showing 1. What does that mean? Is it has only one physical core and 2 logical cores? Is mesi cache coherence protocol is applicable in this case?

Answer (score 2):

From Intel's Architecture Manual, Volume 3:

> 8.7.13.1 "Processor Caches"
>
> For processors supporting Intel Hyper-Threading Technology, the caches are shared. Any cache
>   manipulation instruction that is executed on one logical processor has
>   a global effect on the cache hierarchy of the physical processor.

In my understanding, it means that you have 1 physical core, with Hyper-Threading enabled, giving you 2 logical cores. These logical cores share almost all of the resources of the physical core, including all the caches, therefore there is no need for cache coherence protocols, both cores always see the same cache state.

An interesting side-effect of this is mentioned on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading:

> In May 2005 Colin Percival demonstrated that on the Pentium 4, a
>   malicious thread can use a timing attack to monitor the memory access
>   patterns of another thread with which it shares a cache, allowing the
>   theft of cryptographic information.

Comment: The distinction between modified and not-modified is still significant (on replacement, a modified cache line must be written back) as is the distinction between valid and invalid (caches might start with all lines invalid and if any I/O devices do not snoop the cache system software may flush cache lines to make them visible to such devices). With an inclusive L2 cache, if an I/O device snoops the cache system, the L2 would naturally filter snoops from reaching L1 which requires additional states.